# Arrange char array in sequence

Tags: java, alphabet

I came across a post showing how to arrange char array by alphabet order.
seeing this can be done, I want to output the alphabetical order of each character of the input string, in order of the characters of the input string.

I'm a bit stuck.  I can get the string reordered alphabetically, but I don't know what to do next.

example is 'monkey' to '354216'

because 'ekmnoy' e is alphabetically first from the set of given characters so e = 1 , k is the second alpha char when sorted so k = 2, and so on.

if you cannot understand I can provide more example to make things clear out.

### Code

```
    String str = "airport";
        Character[] chars = new Character[str.length()];
        for (int z = 0; z < chars.length; z++) {
            chars[z] = str.charAt(z);
        }


        Arrays.sort(chars, new Comparator<Character>() {
            public int compare(Character c1, Character c2) {
                int cmp = Character.compare(
                        Character.toLowerCase(c1.charValue()),
                        Character.toLowerCase(c2.charValue()));
                if (cmp != 0) {
                    return cmp;
                }
                return Character.compare(c1.charValue(), c2.charValue());
            }
        });


        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(chars.length);
        for (char c : chars) {
            sb.append(c);
        }
        str = sb.toString();

        System.out.println(sb);
```

### Output

```
aioprrt
```

### expected output

```
Orange -> aegnOr
561432 -  123456

Monkey -> ekMnoy
354216 -> 123456
```

Comment: It seems to me this post is the answer... What is your question?

Comment: my question is i am only able to arrange them in order but i need that string to be in number, and what is the down vote for ?

Comment: Please give more examples, i can't understand what you want.

Comment: Let say the word 'orange' , this will arrange to 'aegnor' by the program. Now the word orange will need to be display in a number string  as '561432' in the order of the alphabet appearance.

Comment: but for this number string you dont need to sort the word alphabetically before.

Comment: To obtain this number , I need to sort it before I can determine the order? Or is there a better way ?

Comment: @kai I will this it now , just now i am still figuring myself

Comment: Here is a shorter way to convert the String to an char array: Character[] chars = str.toCharArray(); and the other way around:  str = String.valueOf(chars);

Comment: Do remove the down vote to whom that done it. I dont see why it should be down voted as i fulfill all the requirement to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know what you want to do with double characters, but if you add this few lines to your code at the end you are getting the right result. **Iterate over the sorted String and replace the charakters in the original String with their indices in the sorted String.**

```
String originalStr = "airport";
for(int i = 0; i<str.length(); i++) {
    originalStr = originalStr.replace(str.charAt(i), String.valueOf(i+1).charAt(0));
}
System.out.println(originalStr);
```

Output: 1254357

If you want to get the output: 1254367 use `replaceFirst`:

```
 originalStr = originalStr.replaceFirst(String.valueOf(str.charAt(i)), String.valueOf(i+1));


Input:Orange
Output:561432

Input:Monkey
Output:354216
```

The whole code:

```
    String str = "airport";
    String originalStr = str; //creat a backup of str because you change it in your code
    Character[] chars = str.toCharArray();


    Arrays.sort(chars, new Comparator<Character>() {
        public int compare(Character c1, Character c2) {
            int cmp = Character.compare(
                    Character.toLowerCase(c1.charValue()),
                    Character.toLowerCase(c2.charValue()));
            if (cmp != 0) {
                return cmp;
            }
            return Character.compare(c1.charValue(), c2.charValue());
        }
    });

    str = String.valueOf(chars);
    System.out.println(str);


    //Iterate over the sorted String and replace the charakters in the original String with their indices in the sorted String
    for(int i = 0; i<str.length(); i++) {
        originalStr = originalStr.replaceFirst(String.valueOf(str.charAt(i)), String.valueOf(i+1));
    }
    System.out.println(originalStr);
```

Comment: Question is looking for alphabetical order of characters in the input string, not position of the character in the original string.

Comment: "Now the word orange will need to be display in a number string as '561432' " he said that he want to do it like this and this is exactly the output he would get from my code!

Comment: He said: "such that the word 'airport' to '1254367' " thats what i done...:/ you think i did understood this question.

Comment: Str is the same as origstr, assuming you are extending op's example code. Airport -> 1234567 was a confusing description trying to describe identifying the index of the alphabetically sorted string, look at the expected outputs, where the relative alphabetical order is represented beneath each string

Comment: With the latest edut, removing downvote as this now answers the question (ignoring that str is never defined in your answer and is the orig, not sorted string in the op):-)

Comment: i am using his code. so str="airport" was changed to str = "aioprrt" when i use it in my code and origStr = "airport". so they have never been the same.

Comment: and i know that str is never defined in my answer, because i said he should add this code at the end of his code...and he defined str. i will post the whole code that you can understand it.

Comment: The comment about the definition of str was because, in an earlier edit, you appeared to be pulling the index of the char from irs position within str, instead of from the sorted list.

Comment: no i never did. i programmed it and the first version i posted here worked.

Comment: I could have misread. Always a possibility, especially at 3am ;)

Answer (score 1):

Once you have arranged the characters in order (in a different array from the original) then create a third array by walking the original string and choosing the index of each character from te sorted string.

```
input:  edcba
sorted: abcde
index:  01234
```

Pseudocode...

```
for( int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++ ) {
    index[i] = sorted.indexOf(input[i]);
}
```

Result should be 43210 with the given input.

Note that strings with more than 10 characters will result in ambiguous output, which can be handled by inserting spaces in the output. Example:

```
abcdefghijk -> 
012345678910
```

Comment: Wbat if there are two of the same letters in a string?

Comment: @Dariusz OP has not defined the expected result. In the algorithm I describe, the result will depend upon how they choose to handle the sort. If 'aab' is sorted as 'ab', then output will be '112'.  If, on the other hand, it is sorted as 'aab', output will be '113'. Bots 'a's are expected evaluate to 1because of typical early exit search strategies starting from the start of the string (and no special care or requirement or implied requirement was given to search backwards)

Comment: @Dariusz  thanks for reminding me of 2 similar letter appearing like the word 'APPLE'. I will try to work this out before I start another question on this

Answer (score 0):

You can use this below code:

```
package Test;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Arrange {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "money";
        List<Test> strs=new LinkedList<Test>();
        List<Test> final_result=new LinkedList<Test>();
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
        {
            Test t=new Test(i, ""+str.charAt(i), 0);
            strs.add(t);
        }
        Collections.sort(strs,new Comparator<Test>() {
               @Override
               public int compare(Test o1, Test o2) {
                   return (o1.getS().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getS()));
               }
           });
        Integer i=1;
        for (Test st : strs) {
           st.setJ(i);
           final_result.add(st);
           i++;
       }
        Collections.sort(final_result,new Comparator<Test>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Test o1, Test o2) {
                return (o1.getI().compareTo(o2.getI()));
            }
        });
        for (Test test : final_result) {
            System.out.println(test.getJ());
        }
   }
}

class Test{
    private Integer i;
    private String s;
    private Integer j;
    public Test() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public Test(Integer i, String s, Integer j) {
        super();
        this.i = i;
        this.s = s;
        this.j = j;
    }
    public Integer getI() {
        return i;
    }
    public void setI(Integer i) {
        this.i = i;
    }
    public String getS() {
        return s;
    }
    public void setS(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }
    public Integer getJ() {
        return j;
    }
    public void setJ(Integer j) {
        this.j = j;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((i == null) ? 0 : i.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((j == null) ? 0 : j.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((s == null) ? 0 : s.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Test other = (Test) obj;
        if (i == null) {
            if (other.i != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!i.equals(other.i))
            return false;
        if (j == null) {
            if (other.j != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!j.equals(other.j))
            return false;
        if (s == null) {
            if (other.s != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!s.equals(other.s))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: the output is wrong.. as it differ from my example the output for money
 is 24315, not 41325

Comment: Refer to my example on top. As for 'money' it will be arrange to 'emnoy' in alphabetical order therefor 24315->money